# Identifying optimal variable value to optimize classification

Tags: r, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm, genetic-programming

I have a function:

```
function <- function(a, b, c, d){...}
```

I cannot provide the function, but I don't think it is necessary for this as it is more of a theoretical question.

I have a range of values for each variable: a = [3, 10], b = [50, 100], c = [20000, 70000], d = [70000, 120000].

I want to determine what parameters maximize the function through an algorithm which learns based on the output of the algorithm.

I was looking into genetic algorithms, particle swarm optimization, and simulated annealing, but because all of input values must be positive integers, I am having trouble identifying the right algorithm or way to set it up so that I could make it use only integers.

For example, for genetic algorithms, I have tried the following:

```
GA::ga(type="real-valued", fitness = function, min = c(3, 50, 100, 70000), max = c(10, 150, 70000, 120000), parallel = TRUE)
gramEvol::GeneticAlg.int(genomeLen = 4, genomeMin = c(3, 50, 1000, 70000), genomeMax = c(10, 150, 70000, 120000), evalFunc = function, plapply = mclapply)
```

I get errors in my function related to the fact that non integer values are being fed into the function. How can I make it consider only integer functions?

Thanks!

Comment: Write a wrapper-function, which takes in reals and calls the function with rounded ints.

Comment: @Sascha This method would return the same result, say for example for 3.1 and 3.2. This would be computationally inefficient, and the function itself takes 3-4 mins to run. Is it possible to modify GA to only use integer values?

Comment: Depends on how those values are chosen (GA design-decision). You can also cache previous evals not to recalculate an already know objective.  Additionally with those (Meta-)heuristics there is not much sound theory. The approach mentioned would kill every gradient/hessian-based approach, but for those methods you use it could be fine. From a theory-side there is also nothing you can do without assumptions about your function (except random search / brute-force)!

Comment: @Sascha Sorry, I am a beginner with GA so I am a bit confused. What would the code be to set it to cache previous evals? What do you mean by it would kill every gradient/hessian based approach? 

My function is going to be very random, as I am changing parameters in length of vector and number of samples, etc to look at AUROC of glmnet classification.

Comment: Caching? Again: a wrapper. It checks against previous evals and if not available, call the function. If you are new to coding this can even be linear-search to all previous evals (you can only produce 480 evals a day; this can be searched <0.01secs). I mentioned smooth-optimization approaches (which are based on stronger theory), where those integers can't be used (without branch-and-bound) as smoothness assumptions are killed off. But for those metaheuristics it does not matter. If the function is very random, it's hard to anything better than random-search.

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions. Would it be possible for you to provide an example of how this wrapper function would work? 
`wrapper <- function(a, b, c, d){
  a <- round(a, 0)
  b <- round(b, 0)
  c <- round(c, 0)
  d<- round(d, 0)
  function(a, b, c, d)
}`
I think I understand the rounding part but not the caching.

Comment: No sorry. I don't have even R on my system. It's very basic though. GA is fed the wrapper, which takes reals. The wrapper rounds the reals. Then it does a search (linear is easiest) on some 2d-int-vector like ```[[4,55,20000,70000],[8,60,75000,110000], ...]``` and if there is a row corresponding to the current calling-candidate input, return (previously calculated) obj from a vector like ```[17, 20, ...]``` where row_i from before corresponds to row_i in the objectives. If search fails: call your function with the cand and add the cand and obj to those arrays after, return the result.

Comment: You also might want to enforce bounds additionally to rounding though. (as a non-GA user i don't know if this would be a possible option to the GA-lib though).